# Angular, Promises, ngResource

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise

So Im having a hard time trying to get my head wrapped around promises in angularJs. I have mixed around my code to try to do some brute force/reverse engineering understanding of it but nothing is coming out to any viable conclusion.

My Code: 
Is is making a call back to get a list of repositories that I manage. These are just stored in the database as basic objects with an id and url.

Here is my view. It allows to me delete, view, and clear metadata in my database about these repos.

```
<div class="container" ng-controller="adminCtrl as vm">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3">

            <label class="control-label" >Repos:</label>
            <div ng-repeat="repo in vm.repos">
                    <div class="clearfix">{{repo.URL}}<br>
                        <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click='vm.listFiles(repo.URL)'>View Files</button>
                        <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click='vm.clearFiles(repo.URL)'>Clear Files</button>
                        <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click='vm.clearRepo(repo.URL)'>Delete Repo</button>
                    </div>
                    <br>
                </div>

            <label class="control-label" >Files:</label>
            <div ng-repeat="file in vm.files">
                <li>{{file.FullPath}}</li>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /.row -->
</div>
```

Here is my controller with some basic functions

```
(function (angular) {
'use strict';
var ngModule = angular.module('myApp.adminCtrl', []);
ngModule.controller('adminCtrl', function ($scope, $resource) {

    //"Global Variables"
    var File = $resource("/api/file/:repoUrl");
    var Repo_del = $resource("/api/repo/:repoUrl");
    var Repo = $resource("/api/repo");

    var vm = this;
    vm.files = [];
    vm.repos = [];

    vm.clearFiles = clearFiles;
    vm.listFiles = listFiles;
    vm.clearRepo = clearRepo;

    init();

    //Anything that needs to be instantiated on page load goes in the init
    function init() {
        listRepos();
    }

    function listRepos() {
        vm.repos = Repo.query();
    }

    //Lists all files 
    function listFiles(url) {
        vm.files = File.query({repoUrl: url});
    }

    function clearRepo(url) {
        Repo_del.remove({repoUrl: url});
    }

    function clearFiles(url) {
        File.remove({repoUrl: url});
    }

    });
}(window.angular));
```

Now this works fine and dandy. It brings back the repos and list them. I can delete, view, and remove with all the functions.

My issue came up with when I was trying to make a list item disappear on delete (instead of needing a page load). To do this I needed to find the index of the item being deleted in the array and remove it. I was gonna use some lodash to do this.Seemed simple enough. My problem is, my vm.repos array is not available within the controller.

For example. When I try to print out vm.repos with a console log within the listRepos function like so

```
function listRepos() {
            vm.repos = Repo.query();
            console.log(vm.repos);
        }
```

I get nothing back from console.log. So this is telling me its not being assigned. Which to me is peculiar because the list is showing up in the ng-repeat on the view using vm.repos.

I have also ran into a problem when I am able to print out the array. It has TONS of promise information in it. For example if I put the console.log in the init() function I will get an array back that is jammed packed with information under a Resource object.

Im not sure how to go about and parse this down to be a manageable object. Looking at basic [guides](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource) I have found some examples but nothing I can translate into my situation.

How do I properly handle api/resource promises?

---

Another problem im having is being able to mock out all of the api responses in my tests. This is my next feat. I do not care if it gets addressed here but I feel its stemming from the same problem.

Here is my only test I was able to write for this controller.

```
'use strict';

describe('adminCtrl', function () {

    beforeEach(function () {
        module('myApp.adminCtrl');
        module('myApp');


    });
    describe('listRepos()', function () {
        it('should return a json object representing a repository',
            inject(function (_$httpBackend_, $rootScope, $controller) {
                var scope = $rootScope.$new();
                var mockBackend = _$httpBackend_;
                var expectedResponse = {id: 12345, url: "https://github.com/myuser/myrepo.git"};

                mockBackend.expectGET('/api/repo').respond([expectedResponse]);

                var ctrl = $controller('adminCtrl', {$scope: scope});

                mockBackend.flush();

                expect(ctrl.repos.length).toEqual(1);
                console.log(ctrl.repos[0]);
                expect((angular.equals(ctrl.repos[0], expectedResponse)));
            }));
    });

});
```

Sorry if this is alot. Hopefully this isnt a repeated question.

---

EDIT to show what im trying now.

```
function clearRepo(url) {
        $http.delete('/api/repo/', {params: {repoUrl: url}}).then(function (){
            //DO THINGS
        });
```

Express:

```
app.delete('/api/repo/:repoUrl', repoCtrl.clear);
```

repoCtrl.clear

```
module.exports.clear = function (req, res) {
    var repoURL = req.params.repoUrl;
    //console.log(repoURL);
    Repo.remove({URL: repoURL}, function(err, results) {
        if (err) {
            console.log("ERR: " + err);
        } else {
            console.log('\n' + repoURL + ' repo deleted... \n');
        }
    });
```

Error im getting:

```
DELETE http://localhost:3000/api/repo/?repoUrl=https:%2F%2Fgithub.com%2Fuw34%2Fmyrepo.git 404 (Not Found)
```

Comment: AIUI, you should use your explicit `$scope` instead of `vm` (which `== this`) in your controller code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the promise:

- Used by $http
- Allow chaining async request

Works like this :

```
var promise = $http.get('/api/values');
promise.then(function(response) {
  $scope.displayData = response.data;
});
```

It is the new way to avoid simple callback (why avoid callback ?? [check this CallbackHell](http://callbackhell.com/) :))

---

Nevertheless, callback can be complicated, hard to follow for debug and everyone prefer write sync code.

To simplify, Angular allow you to code something which look like sync code (but internally, it is async). To do it, $resource encapsulate a promise.

```
// this code return an empty array, then after received server respond, it will populate the empty array with data.
var values = VALUES.query();

// A simple version of it can be code like this
function simpleQuery() {
  var arrayReference = [];

  $http.get('api/values').then(function(response) {
    // populate array reference with data received from server
    angular.forEach(response.data, function(value) {
      arrayReference.push(value);
    });
    // after the return, angular run a $digest 
    // which will display all newly received data thank to biding on your view
  });

  return arrayReference ;
}
```

By doing this, I return an empty array which will be populate on server response.

It is possible to get the promise from a $resource if you prefer :

```
var promise = Repo.query().$promise;
promise.then(function(response) {
  $scope.displayData = response.data;
});
```

---

In 2020, you will probably use [Async/Await](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2015/10/asyncawait-the-hero-javascript-deserved.html) instead $resource ;)

If you want more information, don't hesitate.

Comment: Thanks! This helped me wrap my head around it.

Comment: So I am using $http and it works dandy. Now im refactoring my code away from using $resource and having problems translating when I need to send back information. How do you append params to send back to the api?

Comment: Sorry but i'm not sure what you want to do... Can you give me an example :)

Comment: So originally I was doing a delete this way.

`Repo_del.remove({repoUrl: url});`
I have change it to do it this way. 
 `$http.delete('/api/repo/', {params: {repoUrl: url}}).then(function (){
                //DO THINGS
            });`
Sending these params back. Unfortunately this breaks what im working on. Which now im assuming is the Express routing. 
          


Express is this
`app.delete('/api/repo/:repoUrl', repoCtrl.clear);`

Comment: I updated the question to what im trying to do and whats not working

Comment: just do $http.delete('/api/repo/'+url);

Comment: I tried that previously but that doesn't work. Plus doesn't that fall under bad practice? When the api endpoint would need to be hardcoded to a specific parameter instead of a dynamic one.

Comment: and this $http.delete('/api/repo/'+encodeURIComponent(url)); :)

Comment: interesting. that worked quite well. thanks for the quick responses!

Comment: Nice ! You're welcome. I think you don't have the choice... It is (almost) what $resource do internaly.